# (Date / Time) checker for XML Feed not returning a valid result

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml

I'm trying to debug an emergency alert script. It should be checking to see if the XML item is less than '40000000000' seconds old and echo 'Its been less than 24 hours'. I set it to a crazy high number and it's still returning "else".

```
<?php

$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://content.getrave.com/rss/harpercollege/channel1");
foreach($xml->channel->item as $child)
{
    unset($titleVal, $descriptionVal, $pubdate, $dateString);
    $titleVal = (string)$child->title;
    $descriptionVal = (string)$child->description;
    $pubDate = (string)$child->pubDate;
    $pubDate= date("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime($pubDate));  
    echo $titleVal . "<br>" . $descriptionVal . "<br>" . $pubDate . "<br>";
    if($pubDate > time() + 40000000000) {
        echo 'Its been less than 24 hours';
    } else {
        echo '24 Hours have passed';
    }

} 
?>
```

Comment: Did you look at the date in the file?? Its `Fri, 29 Oct 2021 13:25:47 GMT`

Comment: Yes i gave it 1268 years of additional time.

Comment: But in the wrong direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are using has a `<pubDate>Fri, 29 Oct 2021 13:25:47 GMT</pubDate>` So, for testing purposes fake a sensible date so you know what should be happening, then you dont have to change the code to do riduculous things and you are actually testing in a real situation and wont have to amend the code to work properly with real data! Never a good idea!!!

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://content.getrave.com/rss/harpercollege/channel1");
foreach($xml->channel->item as $child)
{
    unset($titleVal, $descriptionVal, $pubdate, $dateString);
    $titleVal = (string)$child->title;
    $descriptionVal = (string)$child->description;
    $pubDate = (string)$child->pubDate;
    $pubDate= date("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime($pubDate));  

    ### Uncomment one or the other of these KNOWN dates    
    # fake a sensible date time less than 24 hours old
    #$pubDate= 'Wed, 19 Oct 2022 13:25:47 GMT';  
    
    # fake a sensible date time GRETAER than 24 hours old
    $pubDate= 'Tue, 18 Oct 2022 13:25:47 GMT';  
    
    #convert it to a timestamp (compare apples and apples and not apples and oranges)
    $pubDate = strtotime($pubDate);
 
    # Test the pubDate against NOW, time() MINUS 1 day (24*60*60)
    # Test the pub date is Greater that now minus a days worth of seconds
    if($pubDate > time() - 24*60*60) {
        echo 'Its been less than 24 hours';
    } else {
        echo '24 Hours have passed';
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was doing wrong, thank you! Also thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
<?php

$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://content.getrave.com/rss/harpercollege/channel1");
foreach($xml->channel->item as $child)
{
    unset($titleVal, $descriptionVal, $pubdate, $dateString);
    $titleVal = (string)$child->title;
    $descriptionVal = (string)$child->description;
    $pubDate = (string)$child->pubDate;
    $pubDate= date("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime($pubDate));  
    echo $titleVal . "<br>" . $descriptionVal . "<br>" . $pubDate . "<br>";
    if($pubDate > time() + 40000000000) {
        echo 'Its been less than 24 hours';
    } else {
        echo '24 Hours have passed';
    }

} 
?>
```

but i still didn't understand your need

EDIT;

Date from xml we get is Fri, 29 Oct 2021 13:25:47 GMT which is about a year old
Try using new date which is less then a day old

for example if we suppose `$pubDate is Wed, 18 Oct 2022 04:12:00 GMT`

```
.......
$pubDate= date("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime($pubDate));  
    $pubDate = 'Wed, 18 Oct 2022 04:12:00 GMT';
    echo $titleVal . "<br>" . $descriptionVal . "<br>" . $pubDate . "<br>";
    if($pubDate < time() + 86400) {
        echo 'Its been less than 24 hours';
    } else {
        echo '24 Hours have passed'. $timepls;
    }

} 
?>
```